# How to evaluate the following limit? $\lim\limits_{x\to1}\frac{x^n+x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x-n}{x-1}.$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to evaluate the following limit?

$$\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{x^n+x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x-n}{x-1}.$$

I could simplify but couldn't proceed further

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Set $x-1=y\iff x=y+1, y\to0$ as $x\to1$

and $x^m=(1+y)^m=1+my+O(m^2)$

$$\implies\sum_{m=1}^n x^m=\sum_{m=1}^n[1+my+O(y^2)]=\sum_{m=1}^n1+y\sum_{m=1}^nm+O(y^2)$$

Comment: I don't understand the prevalence of answers that use order notation. In introductory calculus classes--from which this question is drawn--that kind of notation is not permitted. The reason being students are being taught how to think through these sorts of questions carefully, sharpening their intuition. Later when they have good intuition, then by all means use order notation, because they will know how to formalize it. But for now, no.

Answer (score 1):

You can tackle this problem using synthetic division and a simple series. First let's do the following division:
$$\frac{x^n + x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \cdots + x - n}{x-1}$$

That would look like

```
 (x-1)    | x^n     x^n-1    x^n-2    ...    x    1
----------|  1        1        1      ...    1    -n
   1      |  0        1        2      ...    n-1  n       
          |  1        2        3      ...    n    0
```

We can therefor see that

$$\frac{x^n + x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \cdots + x - n}{x-1} = x^{n-1} + 2x^{n-2} + 3x^{n-3} + \cdots + n$$

Plugging in $x = 1$ we get:

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^n + x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \cdots + x - n}{x-1} =  1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n = \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Edit: Oops! I had a $n$ in the denominator instead of a 2. Thanks, Timbuc.

Comment: Care: that $\;n\;$ in the denominator of the last expression must be a $\;2\;$ .